# Association analysis of different angiogenic markers with different time points

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I would like to know the statistical tests which can be used to measure the association of the angiogenic measurements, measured at five different time points, with a biomarker.

```
#sample data

  biomarker  Ang1_1 Ang2_1  Ang1_2 Ang2_2
1 T/T 204.0  138.5 151.0 123.5
2 C/C 167.0  127.4 495.0 148.2
3 T/C  558.0  26.9  431.8  62.6
4 C/C 4004.0  27.2 4192.0  94.4
5 T/T  879.8  140.6  747.5 148.8
6 T/C 308.0  144.6 547.0 156.3
7 T/T  463.0  151.8  472.2 133.4
8 T/T 3039.0  129.8 3546.0  143.1
```

Here, I have included the `biomarker` with two `angiogenic` measurements at consecutive time points for few subjects. I'm looking for some possible association tests to analyze them.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain more clearly the nature of your data.

Comment: @Scortchi have added the information I had, Sorry for the delay.